# I want to insert multiple Image to the folder and path and also some data to database in ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to insert multiple Image to the folder and path and also some data to database in ASP.net MVC.

Action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveProduct(ProductViewModel model, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file)
{
    try
    {
        Product pvm = new Product();
        string upload = string.Empty;
        foreach (var item in file)
        {
            string filename = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(item.FileName);
            string filepath = "~/Images/" + filename;
            item.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"), filename));
            upload += filepath + ":";
        }
        string[] patharray = upload.Split(':');

        pvm.product_name = model.product_name;
        pvm.product_description = model.product_description;
        pvm.is_new = model.is_new;
        pvm.is_discount = null;
        pvm.new_price = model.new_price;
        pvm.old_price = model.old_price;
        pvm.img1 = patharray[0].ToString();
        pvm.img2 = patharray[1].ToString();
        pvm.img3 = patharray[2].ToString();
        pvm.img4 = patharray[3].ToString();
        pvm.category = null;
        pvm.quantity = model.quantity;
        pvm.offer_title = null;
        pvm.star = null;
        pvm.CategoryID = model.CategoryID;
        pvm.SubCategoryID = model.SubCategoryID;
        db.Products.Add(pvm);
        db.SaveChanges();
        Console.WriteLine(pvm.ToString());
    }

    return RedirectToAction("AddProduct");

}
```

View

```
<form class="form-inline">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveProduct", "AdminSide", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {

        <div class="col-md-10"><input type="file" name="file" /></div>
        <div class="col-md-10"><input type="file" name="file" /></div>
        <div class="col-md-10"><input type="file" name="file" /></div>
        <div class="col-md-10"><input type="file" name="file" /></div>

        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" />

    }
</form>
```

Comment: Why not use one input that can take multiple files like `<input type="file" name="file" 
 multiple/>`

Comment: You can use jquery plugins like  http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: thanks guy i solve by using <input type="file" name="file" multiple/>